# Composition of carbon rods in alkaline batteries

Tags: everyday-chemistry, home-experiment, materials, mixtures

The carbon rods in batteries look somewhat similar to graphite, but they do not leave a significant mark on paper. What form of carbon are they? Are they simply just graphite with a large amount of binder (clay) mixed in?

Comment: They could be coated with something or another.  Did you try breaking one in half or smashing one with a hammer and then marking with some part of the interior?

Comment: No, thanks for the suggestion. I'll try when I have another used battery, and post the results as a comment